# Disable warning message from external Lib class

Tags: java, log4j, warnings, jena

I re-read a lot of the topics in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=warnings%20log4j%20disable) but non of answers make the work for me.

What is the problem: I have java code  in which I do:

```
Requirement req = response.getEntity(Requirement.class);
```

And have Warning:

```
WARNING: Property http://localhost/ttrDef-5 could not be parsed as datatype http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime
com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.DatatypeFormatException: Lexical form '2015-06-10' is not a legal instance of Datatype[http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime -> class com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.xsd.XSDDateTime] Lexical form '2015-06-10' is not a legal instance of Datatype[http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime -> class com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.xsd.XSDDateTime] during parse -org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.InvalidDatatypeValueException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '2015-06-10' is not a valid value for 'dateTime'.
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.impl.LiteralLabelImpl.getValue(LiteralLabelImpl.java:339)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Node_Literal.getLiteralValue(Node_Literal.java:39)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.LiteralImpl.getValue(LiteralImpl.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.lyo.oslc4j.provider.jena.JenaModelHelper.handleExtendedPropertyValue(JenaModelHelper.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.lyo.oslc4j.provider.jena.JenaModelHelper.fromResource(JenaModelHelper.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.lyo.oslc4j.provider.jena.JenaModelHelper.createObjectResultList(JenaModelHelper.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.lyo.oslc4j.provider.jena.JenaModelHelper.fromJenaModel(JenaModelHelper.java:395)
```

the problem comes from the warning in the **JenaModelHelper** class

```
 catch(DatatypeFormatException e)
                    {
/*1083*/                able(Level.WARNING))

/*1086*/                        logger.log(Level.WARNING, (new StringBuilder()).append("Property ").append(propertyQName.getNamespaceURI()).append(propertyQName.getLocalPart()).append(" could not be parsed as datatype ").append(literal.getDatatypeURI()).toString(), e);
```

So I want to suspend this message, not all other messages but only this. So I do

```
Logger.getLogger(org.eclipse.lyo.oslc4j.provider.jena.JenaModelHelper.class).setLevel(Level.OFF);
Requirement req = response.getEntity(Requirement.class);
```

or

```
Logger.getLogger(org.eclipse.lyo.oslc4j.provider.jena.JenaModelHelper.class).setLevel(Level.FATAL);
Requirement req = response.getEntity(Requirement.class);
```

But nothing happens this warning is still be dumped in the console. I have for loop over this code and passed over 100 times and have 100 warning stacktraces.And that makes problem.

or

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Requirement req = response.getEntity(Requirement.class);
```

I have **log4J.config.xml** but there I do not see nothing for ConsoleAppender.

How to desable warnings just for this class     JenaModelHelper or even package?

Comment: Probably you need to explicitly set logging off in your log4j configuration. Check also where log4j is initializing from.

Comment: '2015-06-10' is indeed not a xsd:dateTime which requires a time.  If you can, set the datatype to xsd:date or fix the lexcial form to include `T00:00:00' or some suitable time.

Comment: "@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")" is about *compiler warnings*, not runtime warnings.

Comment: @AndyS how to understand from where  log4j is initializing from in the external library?

Comment: This is an issue with JenaModelHelper -- ask the developers.  It is from OSCL4j, not Jena.

Answer (score 0):

this will get your job done perfectly:

```
final PrintStream err = new PrintStream(System.err);
System.setErr(new PrintStream("/dev/null"));

// ...

System.setErr(err); // dont forget to close it
```